# How do I have a running sum count/calculation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have found myself in a challenging scenario which I cannot figure out. I have a table "#PriceChange" which i need to figure out the various profit losses, between two dates, based on the price change

Example:

Product 1001 (Black Jeans), has change price 3 times.

- 2014-11-02: 10.99 > 8.99  (50 sold)
- 2014-11-03: 8.99 > 4.99  (25 sold)

I need to calculate, the losses based on the original price.

Along the lines of:

- (10.99 - 8.99) = $2, $2 x **50** = $100 loss
- (8.99 - 4.99) = $4, $4 x **25** = $100 loss.

Total loss = $200.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE #PriceChange
(
Product int,
Description varchar(30),
ValidFrom date,
ValidTo date,
CurrentPrice decimal (5,2),
SoldBetweenValidDates int
);

INSERT INTO #PriceChange VALUES (1001,'Black Jeans','2014-11-01','2014-11-01', 10.99, 100);
INSERT INTO #PriceChange VALUES (1001,'Black Jeans','2014-11-02','2014-11-02', 8.99, 50);
INSERT INTO #PriceChange VALUES (1001,'Black Jeans','2014-11-03',NULL, 4.99, 25);
INSERT INTO #PriceChange VALUES (1002,'Shirt','2014-11-01','2014-11-01', 10.99, 100);
INSERT INTO #PriceChange VALUES (1002,'Shirt','2014-11-02','2014-11-02', 8.99, 50);
INSERT INTO #PriceChange VALUES (1002,'Shirt','2014-11-03',NULL, 4.99, 25);

SELECT  *
FROM    #PriceChange

DROP TABLE #PriceChange
```

Comment: can you please explain how do one determine original price and there could be multiple records or price change per day?

Comment: The original price would be the first "validFrom" date in the period. in the above example, the original price may have been $150. But for November, the original price is $10.99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with cteprice as
(   select *, 
    row_number() over(partition by product order by validfrom) as rnk 
    from #PriceChange)

select  p1.Product, 
        sum((p1.CurrentPrice - p2.CurrentPrice)* p2.SoldBetweenValidDates) 
from cteprice p1
join cteprice p2 on p1.rnk + 1 = p2.rnk and p1.Product = p2.Product
group by p1.Product
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT  
         p1.Product
         , OverallDiff
      FROM    
         #PriceChange p1
      CROSS APPLY
      (
         SELECT 
            MIN(p2.ValidFrom) as ValidP2
         FROM
            #PriceChange p2
         WHERE
            p1.Product = p2.Product
         AND p1.ValidTo < ISNULL(p2.ValidFrom,'9999-12-31')
       ) as p2
       CROSS APPLY
       (
          SELECT 
            (p1.CurrentPrice-p3.CurrentPrice) * (p1.SoldBetweenValidDates - p3.SoldBetweenValidDates) AS OverallDiff
          FROM
             #PriceChange p3
          WHERE
             p1.Product = p3.Product
          AND p2.ValidP2 = p3.ValidFrom
       ) AS p3
     )
     SELECT
         Product 
         , SUM(OverallDiff) AS OverallDiff
     FROM
         cte
     GROUP BY
         Product
```

Comment: Thank you for the query above. If i can add, what if:

- There is more than 3 price changes in a specific period?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method using `CROSS APPLY` which finds and uses the previous period's price and quantity to calculate the loss.

```
SELECT pc.Product, SUM(loss.TotalLoss) as TotalLoss
FROM    #PriceChange pc
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 (pc_prev.CurrentPrice - pc.CurrentPrice) *
        pc.SoldBetweenValidDates as TotalLoss
    FROM #PriceChange pc_prev
    WHERE pc_prev.Product = pc.Product AND pc_prev.ValidTo < pc.ValidFrom
    ORDER BY pc_prev.Product, pc_prev.ValidTo DESC
) loss
GROUP BY pc.Product
```

---

```
Product     TotalLoss
----------- ---------------------------------------
1001        200.00
1002        200.00
```